# How to name an array object with a var String in Google Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to set a var string to the name of my array object (see newName). But if I use the code below the arrayobject is named "newName" instead of "test". Can somebody help me out?

```
var newName = "test"    
var productData = {
  newName : index,
  "productName" : productName,
  "currentInventory" : currentInventory,
  "lastModified" : lastModified
 }
```

Comment: Populate it without `newName`, then `productData[newName] = index;`

Comment: `newName : index,` -> `[newName] : index,`